# VB.net Visual basic: Creating an applocation/json string from a dictionary with sub arrays

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem creating a JSON array containing sub arrays in VB.Net Visual Basic.  I've tried a number of different approaches, and can't figure out how to get the sub array to appear as an array (it's missing the [ and ]).
My current code (shortened here for clarity's sake) is:

```
    Dim EEID As String = oEE.ID
    Dim EEDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
      {"EmployeeCode", EEID},
      {"FirstName", Replace(oEE.firstname, ",", " ")},
      {"MiddleName", Replace(oEE.middleName, ",", " ")},
      {"LastName", Replace(oEE.lastname, ",", " ")},
      {"Phone", oEE.homePhone},
      {"EMail", oEE.emailAddress},
      {"StartDate", CDate(oEE.hireDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")},
    }
    Dim IdDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
      {"ID", EEID & "@" & oEE.co & ".TWP"}
    }
    EEDict.Add("Identifiers", IdDict)
    Dim VarDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
      {"EmployeeType", oEE.empType},
      {"Department", oEE.cc1},
      {"Home1", "SelfEdit"}
    }
    Dim StateDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
      {"EffectiveDate", DataEffDate},
      {"Variables", VarDict}
    }
    EEDict.Add("States", StateDict)
    Dim NewEEData As String = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EEDict)
```

This creates a serialized object like this (it's missing the [ and ] :

```
    {   
      "EmployeeCode":"020000",
      "FirstName":"First",
      "MiddleName":"Middle",
      "LastName":"Last",
      "StartDate":"2003-01-01",
      "Identifiers"
        :{
          "ID":"020000@3179.TWP"
        },
      "States"
        :{
          "EffectiveDate":"2020-11-01",
          "Variables"
            :{
              "EmployeeType":"RFT",
              "Department":"406110",
              "Home1":"SelfEdit"
            }
         }
      }
```

I've tried serializing the sub dictionaries before adding to the main object with:

```
    EEDict.Add("Identifiers", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IdDict))
    Dim StateDict As New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
      {"EffectiveDate", DataEffDate},
      {"Variables", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VarDict)}
    }
    EEDict.Add("States", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StateDict))
```

And all this does is add slashes between the braces, still no [ ].

```
    "States":"
      {
        \"EffectiveDate\":\"2020-11-01\",
        \"Variables\":\" 
        {
           \\\"EmployeeType\\\":\\\"RFT\\\",
           \\\"Department\\\":\\\"406110\\\",
           \\\"Home1\\\":\\\"SelfEdit\\\"
        }\"
      }"
```

The output should look something like this:

```
    "States": [
      {
        "EffectiveDate": "Type: DateValue, Notes: YYYY-MM-DD",
        "Variables": 
         {
           "EmployeeType": "Type: StringValue",
           "Title": "Type: StringValue",
           "Department": "Type: StringValue",
           "Home1": "Type: StringValue"
         }
      }
    ]
```

When I go to submit the array, it returns null error in the Identifiers (the first sub array) section, no ID found.  Can someone please point me into the right direction.

Comment: I figured out part of the problem;  I was "serializing" the sub arrays more then once.  I found a example in C# that uses a class object with public properties. C is not my strongest language here so I need to interpret and convert  to see if it works for my application.

Comment: There are some nice (free) online code converters that can convert working C# to vb.net.  https://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: the Newtonsoft web site has some really great examples of objects and corresponding json after serialization. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm

Comment: Thanks!  Bookmarked the newtonsoft site.  The converter threw an exception in my browser; it's blocked for one reason or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `States` to be a `List(of object)` instead of `Dictionary(of object, object)`

```
Dim StateDict As New List(Of Object) From {
  {"EffectiveDate", DataEffDate},
  {"Variables", VarDict}
}
EEDict.Add("States", StateDict)
```

`List(of object)` is delimited by square brackets that you need `[ { obj } ]`.

`Object` is delimited by braces `{ name:value }`.

`Dictionary(of String, Object)` will do `{ name: { obj } }`

Comment: tgolisch;  Spot on!  That was the part that I was missing.  I'm furthering the solution by using a class object, and your comment about how the directory and list objects serialize is the key.  Simply awesome!  Thanks!  This is sample code from the class object that looks like is going to work, based on your comment.
    Public Identifiers As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))
    Public Variables As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Public States As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))